# Form builder and theming variables in symfony 4

Tags: twig, symfony4

There are situations where my form inputs would have icons, and some without. Originally, I thought I would be able to put the class within the form builder like so:

```
$builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
            'label' => 'Email address',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'john.smith@foo.com',
                'class' => 'has_icon icon_email'
            ],
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Enter an email address.'
                ])
            ]
        ])
```

And then the output within the form template could potentially take the class and reconfigure the appearance. Clearly this isn't working, but this was the direction I was going in:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form_row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {% if form.vars.attr.class == 'has_icon' %}
            test
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Is this the right approach or is there another more dependable way of going about this?

---

**Edit 9/22/2019**

I wanted to do a test and it was interesting because if I were to try to access the form's block prefixes, I can by specifying in the form theme like so:

`block_prefixes.2 == "password"` and this will access that array within block prefixes and check for that. However, if I were to access attr then the class option like so:

`attr.class` it will return an error `Key "class" does not exist as the array is empty.` Why is that? How can I readily access the array within attr?

Comment: javascript and/or css

Comment: Uh, but for a form field you can't just "apply an icon to a input" - inputs don't allow for :before/:after pseudos. And if I were to do this from the JS side, that would create a significant hit for each input. I feel like this doesn't seem like the right solution? Is that the only solution?

Comment: What type of icons are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since icons were going to be used in my application from global perspective.

The approach is to firstly extend the `FormType` which in my case was called `FormTypeExtension` which was placed in this hierarchy: `src/Form/Extensions/FormTypeExtension.php`

That file outlined:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public static function getExtendedTypes() : iterable
    {
        return [FormType::class];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'icon' => null
        ]);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {

        $view->vars['icon'] = $options['icon'];
    }
}

?>
```

Now within the builder I am able to apply the icon option (which defaults to null thanks to my extension, so in cases form builder doesn't use it):

```
$builder
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
        'label' => 'Email address',
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'john.smith@foo.com'
        ],
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank([
               'message' => 'Enter an email address.'
            ])
        ],
        "icon" => "icon_email"
   ])
```

And now I am able to access that information within my form theme like `{% if icon != null %}` Now I can customize it to how I see fit.

And to also state I love Symfony 4 even more because of how powerful it is! Cheers, hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to make a custom FormType for each input then use a custom fom_widget for each in your theme much like is done in the built-in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PercentType` and `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`

**FormType:**

```
// src:"/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/PercentType.php"

namespace Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\PercentToLocalizedStringTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PercentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addViewTransformer(new PercentToLocalizedStringTransformer($options['scale'], $options['type']));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['symbol'] = $options['symbol'];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'scale' => 0,
            'symbol' => '%',
            'type' => 'fractional',
            'compound' => false,
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedValues('type', [
            'fractional',
            'integer',
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('scale', 'int');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('symbol', ['bool', 'string']);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'percent';
    }
}
```

**form_theme:**

```
// src:"/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig"
...

{% block percent_widget -%}
    {%- if symbol -%}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ symbol|default('%') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock percent_widget %}

...
```

Comment: Hmmmm... Not sure if this is the right way to go about it? Because what if I wanted a password field to have an icon, or a number, text, etc. Doesn't that cause additional work?

Comment: Well, its the way Symfony does it. What I showed you is straight from Symfony source files.

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach could work. You just need to get the variable of the correct child of your form and not the entire form. This should work (in this case on **email)**:

```
{% if form.email.vars.attr.class == 'has_icon icon_email' %}
    do or show something here
{% endif %}
```

or to simply test for your single class `has_icon`:

```
{% if 'has_icon' in form.email.vars.attr.class %}
    do or show something here
{% endif %}
```

For *any* field field as you described in your comment, I guess you need to iterate over all form children and see if they contain the class you are testing for. Something like this:

```
{% for input in form.children  %}
    {% if 'has_icon' in input.vars.attr.class | default %}
        do or show something here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the `| default` is there for fields without the class attribute. Also, I immage you want to render the input field in the same iteration, so you can actually render your icon in the right place. This should get you started I hope.

Comment: Does this mean I have to check literally every form variable instance? Is there no way to just check if any input has the "has_icon" class so that I don't have to manually update this every time I create a new instance of has_icon?

Comment: Just look at the last bit of code I put my my answer. This will make it possible to just check for "has_icon" anywhere in the class.

Comment: Yeah but that is specifically for "email" in form, not blank slated for any input element.

Comment: Which means, if I have more than one input that requires an icon, I have to manually keep updating each individual one, which seems ridiculous to me.

Comment: I thought you would render all fields individually, given the `form_row` in your code, bu so you're saying that you just want to render the whole form? Sorry, its not entirely clear to me what you try to achieve.

Comment: This is what I mean, in your current example you're specifying "email," instead of, say "input." Is there a way to make it less specific, so it fits into any input that has the `.has_icon` class, or do you have to explicitly specify the type of input?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean and added a third option to my answer.

Comment: The for loop didn't work. Additionally, your second option returned this error: `Neither the property "email" nor one of the methods "email()", "getemail()"/"isemail()"/"hasemail()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".`